# What happens (how to control what happens) to the unused part (unused tail) of a block when writing a small file to a larger block?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ext4

When I write a new, small file (a few hundreds of bytes) to my ext4 filesystem, if I understand well (I am not a specialist of filesystems):

- i) a 4KiB block (with my present filesystem and filesystem setings) is allocated to hold the file data, this allocation gets recorded into the containing directory filesystem metadata, etc
- ii) the file data are actually written to the block (with quite a bit of magics involved in the process for example journaling etc possibly happening)

My question is about the process ii). When starting from a 4KiB block that already has data written on it (because it has been used in the past and "de-allocated" but still contains the now unused bytes it was holding when it was used last), and a small file of for example 100B is written to it, what happens to the "tail" of the block (i.e. the last 4KiB - 100B (maybe a bit more than 100B should be removed if there are some metadata or else I do not know about?))? Is this tail overwritten with 0s? with random bytes? unmodified / kept as it was from before?

Is there a way to control this behavior as a user of the filesystem (i.e. choose typically between i) keeping pre-existing bytes on the tail of the block as is, ii) overwriting the tail of the block with 0s, iii) overwriting the tail of the block with random data?)

I am using ext4 (default on Ubuntu 20.04) if this is relevant for the answer.

Comment: I can not comment on ext4, but in for example NTFS those tails are typically zeros. Probably OS smallest buffer is cluster/block sized so even if only 5 bytes are saved to cluster/block, the OS writes cluster sized buffer to the drive. IOW, it allocates some cluster sized area in RAM (which I assume contain zeros at this point), moves the data there and then 'dumps' that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process performs a buffered write, the bytes are copied into the page cache, and then eventually the dirty page will be written to disk.   This can happen for a number of reasons; the program could request a fsync(), the write back timer (typically 30 seconds) could signal that it is time that dirty page should be written to the backing store (specifically, the disk block corresponding to that file's page), or the system could be under memory pressure, and the page will be laundered (or "cleaned"), writing the dirty page to backing store, so that the no-longer-dirty page can be dropped from the page cache to make room for other uses for that memory.

When a process first writes to a page in the page cache, if it is not already in the page cache (and the amount to be written does not fill the entire page), then file system will first have to copy the contents of the file into the page in the page cache.  For example, if the file is exactly 4k long, and you write 111 bytes into the page, we need to preserve the rest of the 3985 pages in the back half of the page.

What if the file is zero-length, or there isn't currently a block allocated for that page in the file?   Well, then we start with a zero-filled page.  There are a couple of reasons for this.  First, reading the old contents of the page is a waste of disk bandwidth.  Secondly, it's a potential security problem.  The previous user of that block might have been a different user.  That no-longer-used block might contain another user's love letters; or it might contain sensitive data, such as medical information, or people's social security numbers.   So you never want to allow the contents of deleted files to leak out; that's considered a bad, **bad** thing to do.

And finally, in the case of ext4, we wouldn't even know what the "old" block would be, since ext4 performs something called "delayed allocation".  Selecting the block that will be used for a newly allocated portion of the file is deferred until the last possible moment --- that is, when we need write back the file.  This allows us to wait until we know how big the file is (most files are fully written within 30 seconds), so we can do a better job of deciding where to place that file on the disk.  In the case of a temp file which is created, written, read by another program, and then deleted, we might not ever need to do the block allocation at all.   (This is quite common in shell scripts, for example.)

So in answer to your question, what happens to the rest of the block of a "tail" of a file which is not a multiple of the file system's block size (which is usually 4k) is that the rest of the file will be zero-filled.   This is necessary for many reasons, as described below, so it's not possible to change this behavior.   In general, while have a knob for something which (a) is slower since it needlessly reads data blocks, and (b) is a walking, talking security vulnerability that could leak user/customer data?

Comment: While I'm aware that you are Ted Ts'o (assuming you are the real one :P), I beg to differ that security problem is a *reason* here. While the residual data will be there anyway until you re-allocate the block to a file, it doesn't really help / hurt much regardless of whether you zero-out the trailing bytes of it. I'd say the reason is really that you can't exactly perform "sub-block" write anyway with ATA/SCSI/NVMe/... write commands, since their payload's atomic unit is logical block, which is so due to the nature of drives / reason of efficiency rather than security.

Comment: The reason why it's a security issue is it's possible for the file to be mmap'ed.  And if you mmap the last 4k of the file, anything left over would be visible, since memory management hardware works in units of pages.    I suppose you could zero the trailing residual space when you page fault in that last block, but why?   And there are a number of other reasons why it's just simply faster, more efficient, and less error prone to simply overwrite the entire block when it is allocated and first written back to disk.

Comment: Oh, and if you leave the residual space containing the previous trailing bytes of the old file, and then someone uses the truncate(2) system call to adjust i_size upwards?   What then?   The page might not even be in the page cache, so at that point, you'd have to read the block into the page cache, zero the bytes, and then make sure the block is written back before the metadata operation is committed to disk.   And it's not just truncate(2) that could cause this to happen, but also fallocate(2).  And if you screw any of this up, it would be a security problem.   It's inherently fragile.

Comment: And here's one more way you could screw up if you left residual bytes non-zero'ed.  Suppose you do a random write beyond i_size?   Now i_size will get adjusted upwards, and the residual bytes will get exposed, once again, potentially revealing private data.   Something which is this fragile is a just a bad idea, because sooner or later, it *will* be a security vulnerability.

Comment: Ah I see, so by security problem you are referring to the fact that often "more than just the file" will be read into the memory because the "read unit" isn't byte in those cases. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I can not comment on EXT4 specifically but,

**Observation on NTFS formatted drives:**

Assume 4KB clusters and cluster only partially used, the 'tail' contains zeros. Here we see the last two bytes of a JPEG (FF D9) as it exists on the drive, the actual end of the file, and zeros trailing it:

[image]

I dig around on drives a lot using disk and hex editors like these, and it's what I consistently see.

If indeed OS and file system is relevant I hope someone more knowledgeable with regards to those parameters (Linux, EXT4) will answer the question from that perspective too.

But I assume it will be similar:

If we look at this from the drive's perspective a sector is the smallest addressable unit. IOW if we need to write even *1 byte* with value FF to sector zero a byte offset zero, we need to write the entire 512 or 4 KB sector. So practically a buffer of 4 KB is allocated, our byte is copied there, and then the entire 4KB gets written to the drive.

It makes no sense to use a 'buffer' that is anything else than filled with zeros, nor to read the sector from the drive and fill our buffer with whatever happens to be in the drive at that location. With regards to the latter, it's simply a waste of time/resources.

It would be sort of like printing to a page that already contains text and images.

Answer (score 2):

Filesystem blocks (or clusters, you name it) are "backed" by logical blocks of a storage drive. With at least command sets used in modern storage interfaces (ATA/SCSI/NVMe/...), there is no way to perform *in-place* sub-logical-block write, i.e., you can't send a few bytes to the drive and tell it to just replace certain bytes with them in a logical block. (Even if there is, no OS would use it anyway.) What you can only do is send a data payload of the size of one or more logical blocks and ask the drive to replace the data on certain logical blocks with that payload.

So if you want to retain data at some ending bytes in a logical block, you must read the data of the block to memory first, and have it modified in memory and write the whole block of data back. This is what would happen if you perform block-level write with e.g. `dd`, given that you don't instruct it to zero-fill those ending bytes.

Now when it comes to the scenario of your concern, it doesn't exactly make sense to retain the data anyway. I mean, while there might be certain somewhat-valid reason that you would like it to happen, from the file point of view, the data has no relevance. Given the fact that it would be inefficient to retain it due to the aforementioned reason, it would only make sense if it simply write whatever that's in the memory pages before you write anything to them, which would be used as the payload eventually.

Now the question become, is it *possible* (I mean like logically) to begin with memory pages that is filled with data other than zeroes? Sure, but again it wouldn't really make sense to, since zeroes more or less carry the semantical meaning of "unused". While some people might have all kinds of reason that they want something other than zeroes, but the thing is regardless of what would be used as the "filling data", the data is irrelevant to the file that is allocated with the block, so it is irrelevant to the **purpose of the filesystem** and would be a "niche" need to cater. Therefore, I'm quite sure no sane OS / filesystem driver would bother to have such "knob", as more code means more (potential) bugs.

P.S. I can hardly see that it has anything to do security, since the residual data *on the drive* will be there anyway until you re-allocate the block (except when e.g. RZAT TRIM is triggered upon file deletion; but then if the block is "practically* zeroed upon deallocation, we have nothing to concern about here anymore). While on the other hand though, it would be indeed a security problem if the memory pages have residual data *on the RAM*, since that would mean some irrelevant (but meaningful / sensitive) data could get "leaked" *to the drive*.

Comment: Actually, ext4 can be used on top of "dax" (direct access) persistent memory.  In that case, it is most certainly possible to do sub-block writes into the pmem.     Persistent memory is $$$ expensive, so it's rare that it will actually be used as the backing store for a file system, but it can be used that way.  The idea was that pmem is faster than memory and if you can afford to pay $$$ for (for example) Intel Optane devices, you could do that.  Unfortunately for Intel, Optane was a commercial failure, and so as a product, it's pining for the fjords....

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, de-allocated sectors with sensitive data
on a HDD could be read by writing a small file to the
disk on top of the existing data, then reading in the
entire sector, as it is allocated entirely to the file.

This was rightfully diagnosed as a security hole by all
the major operating systems and plugged up.

Today (and since very long ago), data that was not
written by the process, cannot be read, and is
substituted usually by zeroes.

My knowledge does not extend to how each
operating system solves this security hole,
whether the last sector of the file is extended with
zeroes when the file is written, or when it's read in
(the first is of course a more secure solution).
However, this security hole decidedly does not exist
any more.

Comment: Thanks! Is zeroing always the method used, or can / is filling with random data also used?

Comment: My gut feeling is that nobody would bother with a random generator that will use resources and slow down the disk.